# VB Script to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, web-scraping

I've acquires an old VBScript that was used to retrived test score that I'm trying to convert to a VB.net Form app.
I'm stuck with this function

```
Function getit()
Dim xmlhttp
Dim pageNum
Dim objStream
Dim objDebugStream


Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
pageNum = 1


Do While pageNum > 0
   Set xmlhttp=CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

   'strURL = DownloadDest
    Wscript.Echo "Download-URL: " & strURL & "&page_num=" & pageNum

    'For basic auth, use the line below together with user+pass variables above
     xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL & "&page_num=" & pageNum, false
    xmlhttp.Send
    Wscript.Echo "Download-Status: " & xmlhttp.Status & " " & xmlhttp.statusText

    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        If Left(LCase(xmlhttp.responseText),16) <> "no records found" Then
            If objStream.State = 0 Then
                objStream.Open
            End If
            objStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody

            If debugEachPage Then
                Set objDebugStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                objDebugStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
                objDebugStream.Open
                objDebugStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody
                objDebugStream.SaveToFile ".\sortest_aleks_" & classCode & "_page_" & pageNum & ".csv"
                objDebugStream.Close
                Set objDebugStream = Nothing
            End If
        Else
            If pageNum = 1 Then
                WScript.Echo "No Records Found for " & classCode
            End If
            pageNum = 0 ' Have to set this to exit loop
        End If
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Response Status of " & xmlhttp.Status & " for " & classCode
    End If

    If pageNum <> 0 Then
        pageNum = pageNum + 1
    End If
    Set xmlhttp=Nothing
Loop

If objStream.State <> 0 Then
    objStream.SaveToFile LocalFile
    objStream.Close
End If
Set objStream = Nothing
```

### End Function

What I wrote looks like this

```
 Private Sub GetALEKSData(ByVal strURL As String)
        REM ======================================================================================================
        ' This Module will access the ALEKS Web Site and access the CofC foreign language scores for the terms indicated days
        ' The Comma Seperated Values (CSV) as then stored in the main form Text Box
        '=========================================================================================================
        Dim ALEKStr As System.IO.Stream = Nothing
        Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing

    Try
        'Create a WebReq for the URL
        Dim WebReq As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)

        'If required by the server, set the credentials.
        WebReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        'Get the Respponse.
        Dim WebResp As System.Net.WebResponse = WebReq.GetResponse

        ' Display the status.


        ' If required by the server, set the credentials.


        ALEKStr = WebResp.GetResponseStream
        srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(ALEKStr)
        ' read all the text 

        TextBox1.Text = srRead.ReadToEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.Text = QQ  REM Wipe Text box to indicate No DATA to Process

    Finally
        '  Close Stream and StreamReader when done
        srRead.Close()
        ALEKStr.Close()
    End Try
    Debug.Print(TextBox1.Text)
    REM Remove NO Data message
    If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "No records match criteria.") > 0 Then TextBox1.Text = QQ

    DataFileHasData = Len(TextBox1.Text) > 0
```

### End Sub

It is returning with :Access denied: wrong3 HTTP header from

Not sure what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub GetALEKSData(ByVal strURL As String)
    REM ======================================================================================================
    ' This Module will access the ALEKS Web Site and access the CofC foreign language scores for the terms indicated days
    ' The Comma Seperated Values (CSV) as then stored in the main form Text Box
    '=========================================================================================================

    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
        Try 
           wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
           TextBox1.Text = wc.DownloadString(strURL)
        Catch
            TextBox1.Text = QQ
        End Try
    End Using    

    Debug.Print(TextBox1.Text)
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("No records match criteria.") Then TextBox1.Text = QQ
    DataFileHasData = Not String.IsNullorWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

And if that doesn't work, the error message says, "Access Denied", so the problem is probably this line:

```
wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

If that *still* doesn't help, install [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare the HTTP requests sent by the old vbscript to the new VB.Net code. You'll be able to see **exactly** what you're missing.

Comment: OK I installed Fiddler...not sure what I'm suppose to be seeing..other than numbers

Comment: Also the error I'm getting is Access denied: wrong3 HTTP header from <ip address>

Comment: also the old script no longer works because of site changes..

However if I type the URL directly into a browswer..I get the data I'm trying to retrieve

Comment: Try setting the user agent. I have scrapes fail for lack of a meaningful user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the UserAgent fixed the issue
Private Sub GetWEBData(ByVal strURL As String)
        REM ======================================================================================================
        ' This Module will access the WEB Web Site and access the CofC foreign language scores for the terms indicated days
        ' The Comma Seperated Values (CSV) as then stored in the main form Text Box
        '=========================================================================================================
        'Clear existing data

```
    Try
        'Create a WebReq for the URL
        Dim WebReq As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strURL), HttpWebRequest)

        'If required by the server, set the credentials.
        WebReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        WebReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"

        'Get the Respponse.
        'Dim WebResp As System.Net.WebResponse = WebReq.GetResponse
        Dim WebResp As HttpWebResponse = CType(WebReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        ' Display the status.
        ' Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusDescription)

        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim WEBtream As Stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream()

        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim srRead As New StreamReader(WEBtream)

        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String = srRead.ReadToEnd()
        ' Display the content.
        TextBox1.Text = responseFromServer
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        'Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)

        ' Cleanup the streams and the response.
        srRead.Close()
        WEBtream.Close()
        WebResp.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("WEB DATA READ ERROR OCCURED", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Program Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```